# Quickbooks online access using QBXML

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, qbxml

Is there a way to have a 'Intuit anywhere' Saas app talk to quickbook online accounts via QBXML?

Our Saas app already connects to desktop versions using QBXML and it would be great if I can reuse same QBXML parsing code and logic, looks like data services xml as described [here](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0400_QuickBooks_Online/0100_Calling_Data_Services/0030_Retrieving_Objects#Paging) are totally different from QBXML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, sort of, but it sucks badly. A bit of detail is here:
 [QuickBooks Online via qbXML](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_online_edition)

Intuit Anywhere applications DO NOT use qbXML. They use IDS. However, you can utilize the qbXML gateway for QuickBooks Online without being an Intuit Anywhere app.

You should know that the qbXML interface to QuickBooks Online has basically been abandoned- Intuit will likely never update it ever again. The functionality is incomplete, and the actual gateway is very, very slow for many types of requests.

HOWEVER, if you're a SaaS application, you probably should NOT be using qbXML at all. You should consider moving to Intuit Anywhere, and using IDS XML instead. This has several benefits:

- You can get featured on AppCenter.Intuit.com, and get marketing benefits via Intuit's marketing channels
- The IDS API for QuickBooks Online as a whole are much, much faster
- The IDS API for QuickBooks Online is much, much more robust
- The IDS API for QuickBooks Online is actually being maintained going forward

Comment: thanks. regarding not using QBXML, it means I have to maintain two sets of modules one for interacting with online edition(IDS XML) and one with desktop edition using QWC(QBXML), I wish quickbooks should have used QBXML everywhere so that porting was easy, why they have to invent another xml format :(

Comment: You misunderstand the history and reasons behind both formats. You *can* use qbXML for everything... it's just that qbXML for QuickBooks Online is clunky/incomplete. However, you can ALSO USE IDS FOR EVERYTHING- QuickBooks Online, AND QuickBooks Desktop support IDS XML. On top of that, IDS XML is much cleaner, and certainly the way of the future. Think of qbXML as "the old way", and IDS XML as "the new way" of doing things. Again, if you're a SaaS application, you should look at IDS/the Intuit Partner Platform- it's a better platform, and the way of the future for QuickBooks integrated apps.

Comment: thanks for the info, how can I use IDS XML to talk with e.g. quick-book pro 2011 using quick-book connector? any links?

Comment: https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services and https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0500_QuickBooks_Windows and https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform

Comment: ok so it is not via quickbook connector, user will have to sync, that is ok, but still different API for online and desktop version...sigh

Comment: The two IDS API/XML "flavors" (one for QuickBooks desktop, one for QuickBooks Online) are very similar. If you're using one of the officially supported DevKits, the differences are generally abstracted away from you. When Intuit releases IDS v3 (probably within the next 6 months), the APIs for QuickBooks Online and QuickBooks desktop will then be identical to each other.

Comment: It would appear the long-term viability of IDS on Desktop was an illusion. All of the links in the comments here to substantiate it are now broken, and any mention of IDS on Intuit's site largely sends you to a blog post about discontinuing a REST API. https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2014/09/08/timeline-to-discontinue-the-quickbooks-desktop-rest-api The desktop version seems to support QBXML, IIF, and that's it. https://developer.intuit.com/docs?redirectid=QBDesktop